# change value of Dropdown based on another one - Ipywidgets

Tags: python, widget, ipywidgets

I am working with `ipywidgets` and need to update the value of a `Dropdwon widget` based on the value of another one. I have found several questions dealing with this and I am using a solution based on `@interact`:

```
my_dict = {'1' : ['A',
                  'B',
                  'C'],
           '2' : ['a',
                  'b',
                  'c']
          }

drop1 = widgets.Dropdown(options = my_dict.keys())
drop2 = widgets.Dropdown()


@interact(ele1 = drop1, ele2 = drop2)
def print_city(ele1, ele2):
    asset_type.options = my_dict[ele1]
```

So far this works fine. However, in my final layout I want to use `HBox` to arrange the final layout with some other widgets. Something like:

```
date1 = [widgets.DatePicker(description='Date1', disabled=False)]
date2 = [widgets.DatePicker(description='Date2', disabled=False)]

first = widgets.HBox([date1[0], drop1])
second = widgets.HBox([date2[0], drop2])

tabs = [widgets.VBox([first, second])]


final = widgets.Tab(children=tabs, continuous_update=True)
final
```

As you can see, I get a double visualisation for the tabs that are linked to each other because of the @interact. What would be a solution to link them and not get a double visualization?

[image]